# which jquery selector to do this?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<div id="m101">
    <table class="tablec" width="80%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tr>
    <td><a href="#"><span class="name">My Name</span></a></td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td><a href="#"><span class="clickme">clickme</span></a></td>
  </tr>
</table>
</div>
```

Which selector should I use to capture the content of "name" if clickme is clicked? There are more than one of those tables with the same classes, but the surrounding divs are unique. The name is different each time.

I've been experimenting the with parent, parents and closest functions so far without luck.

```
 $(".clickme").click(function(){
    var name = $(this).closest('.name').text();
alert(name);
 });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can traverse the tree up until you hit a `<table>`:

```
var name = $( this ).closest( 'table' ).find( '.name' ).text();
```

Comment: Use `closest()` rather than `parents()`.  It's more efficient because `closest()` halts when it finds the first matching ancestor, whilst `parents()` continues up the DOM tree looking for more.

Answer (score 2):

Would something like this do the trick?

```
$(".name", $(this).closest("div")).text()
```

Working example here: http://jsfiddle.net/44re8/

Comment: No, because it's searching for elements with class '.name' within the surrounding div. Try the jsfiddle.

Comment: @AndyE - Oops, helps if I read it properly. Dumb comment deleted.

Answer (score 1):

You are not able to select the `.name` using `closest()` as it is not an ancestor. You would need to select a common ancestor e.g. the `table` and then work back down the tree to the `.name` element.

```
$(".clickme").click(function(){
  var table = $(this).closest("table");
  var name =  table.find('.name').text();
  alert(name);
 });
```

You could have this in a single line using

```
$(".clickme").click(function(){
  var name =  $(this).closest("table").find('.name').text();
  alert(name);
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

This did the work for me

```
function() {
    $(".clickme").click(
        function(e) {
            alert($(this).parents("div").find(".name").html());
        }
    );
}
```

Comment: Do you know why changing the last function html() to text() gives me an entirely different effect? It pulls every single name class from the page. I'm looking for a way to just pull the text and get rid of tags (those are message board posts).

Comment: Oh! Alright. I did this according to the sample provided in your question. :)

Answer (score 0):

Simplest of answers -

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.clickme').click(function(){
    var getName = $('.name').text();
    alert(getName);
});
});
```

Comment: That wouldn't work since as I pointed out there are multiple classes with the same name.

Comment: Alright, why not add a new class to this specific td..? I'm trying to give you the easiest solution. You probably have working solution from the other responses here, which are technically better than what I am suggesting here -
how about this -
$('.clickme.extraClass').click(function(){//remaining code here}

Note the addition of another class - "extraClass" in the jquery, and the same addition is made to the html as well.

See jfiddle here - http://jsfiddle.net/EtxBr/

Comment: how about adding a new class to the element?
see jfiddle here-
http://jsfiddle.net/EtxBr/

This is just another way of doing the same thing, and probably the easiest way, but may not be the best technical solution though! :)

Comment: There are probably tons of ways of doing the same thing. If it ain't broken don't fix it. :P Your example wouldn't work for me since I can't change that class (the tables are created with a php loop. However now I'm trying to figure out why html() returns the content with the html and text() returns ALL of the classes' content without html. I need just the text and from the selected div...